# VS 2017 - This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects (TDS)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, tds

I was using Visual Studio 2015 Professional and recently switched to Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise, as required by my job. The new version of VS won't open my tds projects. It says "This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects. The project types may nto be installed or this version of Visual Studio may not support them." The detail in the migration report says "The application which this project type is based on was not found."

I downloaded and installed Team Development for Sitecore Classic 5.7.0.12, and I tried repairing my VS 2017 installation including .NET Framework 4.6 and 4.7.1 development tools, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you've solved this already. I was looking for answers myself as well, and found the answer on the [TDS hedgehog site](https://www.teamdevelopmentforsitecore.com/Blog/tds-how-to-migrate-tds-projects-2013-2015) about migrating from vs2013 to vs2015, but is also useful in our case.

To define useful, I guess at the time you've started this question you needed to install the TDS version for VS2017. It is included in the downloaded file you've used to install the TDS version for VS2015, or just download it again from the [TDS site](https://www.teamdevelopmentforsitecore.com/Download/TDS-Classic). On that link you might consider using the latest version, or just the TDS version 5.7.0.12 you are using currently.
Of course you need to have a valid license when installing TDS.

And why the TDS site's post about migrating to vs2015 was helpful… think of how you've installed it in the first place. As a Visual Studio extension (vsix file), that is only applied on the Visual Studio version you have installed. Remember this for when you install VS2019 ;-) You then need to download and install TDS version 5.8 or higher, though.

Funny how long questions can remain unanswered and open by the way.

Comment: using the https://www.teamdevelopmentforsitecore.com/Blog/tds-how-to-migrate-tds-projects-2013-2015 steps I have migrated from vs2017 to vs2019